# I declared a variable with const after a function, why is it still accessible there?

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

This code is working, and for me it's strange behaviour, because for 'const' variables shouldn't be hoisted. Could someone explain how and why it works?

```
describe("should dummy tests", () => {

let fixture: ComponentFixture<DummyComponent>;
let component: DummyComponent;
let element: HTMLElement;

beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: declarations
    }).compileComponents();


    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DummyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;

    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it("should dummy text", async () => {
    expect(element.querySelector("dummy-selector")).toBeTruthy();
});
});

const declarations = [DummyComponent];
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the actual function call happens after specifying the 'declarations' variable. Check these two examples:

```
function logNumber() {
  console.log(number)
}

logNumber()

const number = 22
// output: Cannot access 'number' before initialization
```

while:

```
function logNumber() {
  console.log(number)
}

const number = 22

logNumber()
// output: 22
```

In the second example, the global execution context is accessed by the logNumber function call. By the way, 'const' and 'let' variables are also hoisted, but instead of being initialized with 'undefined' they remain uninitialized.

Further info:
[Javascript Execution Contexts](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-execution-context/)

Comment: How does it works that actual function call happens after? Do you know how karma running functions?

Answer (score 1):

The constant just needs to be declared before the code that accesses it is *evaluated* (i.e. when the related function is called).

The order the code is written in doesn't matter.

```js
function example () {
    console.log(`The value of foo is ${foo}`);
}

try {
    example();
} catch (e) {
    console.log("There was an error in the first attempt!");
}
const foo = 1;
try {
    example();
} catch (e) {
    console.log("There was an error in the second attempt!");
}
```